# Rails Production Server Google Font Not Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, unicorn

I have a production server running (digital ocean ruby on rails image [NGINX+UNICORN]), and everything is working except for google fonts. All other fonts that are local are located in the /public/fonts folder and are loaded as http://domain.com/fonts/font.eot. The problem is that the google fonts wont load
`@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,900,300italic,400italic,900italic);`

This makes my application looks really different and makes it sort of ugly. There is a similar question asked here: [Heroku and Google Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948767/heroku-and-google-fonts/18216759#18216759) but that solution does not work. I have also tried adding the  code instead of import but that also does not work. Finally I checked in the network tab of chrome and that does not work as well.

Comment: Have you precompiled the assets? RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Comment: Yes. I ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and in my unicorn config I set the env to production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have moved the `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,900,300italic,400italic,900italic);` to the top of the application.css file and it works now! :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this problem, the solution that worked for me was to comment out the line `config.assets.css_compressor = false` in `config/environments/production.rb`

Hope this helps someone!