# rails, heroku, css & scss: @import works in development but not production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sass, asset-pipeline

In development, in style.css.scss I have:

```
@import'../typography.css';
```

In development, this works because I can see the effects when I load the site.  The `../` is there because landing is located at `app/assets/stylesheets/landing` and typography.css is located at `app/assets/stylesheets`

I run `rake assets:precompile` and `rake assets:clean` locally before pushing.  In production on Heroku, I don't think the css file is being properly called because the effects it should have do not appear.  All other CSS files are being properly called because I can see the styles rendered.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948767/heroku-and-google-fonts

Comment: This is not at all a duplicate.  The answer to that question involved heroku security because it is an external  stylesheet.  I am linking to an internal stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old but I just solved the same problem by omitting the file extension, i.e.

`@import '../typography';`